# Does modifying data in S3 bucket update the data in the FSx-Lustre volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-fsx

I've created a fsx-stack using amazon sagemaker examples repo.
Basically, given the subnet/vpc/security-group and S3 bucket [import mount-path] as an input
it creates a FSx lustre volume.

Question: Would updating the data in one of the subdirectories of the S3 bucket import path reflect in the FSx volume?
If not, would I have to recreate the FSx-stack again to be able to pick up updated data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It can be done.

In the import preferences change that option for "Import Preference" accordingly

- Select here
  [image]
- Choose this option
  [image: update_import_preference]
- Final result
  [image: fsx-import]